# How to allow only the owner of a mysite?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

Mysite sharepoint does a personal site for all user but in my sharepoint 2016, the users have access for another user with URL.

http://domain/my/personal/user/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Documents/Forms/All.aspx

To access in another user i change the user in url :

http://domain/my/personal/anotherUser/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Documents/Forms/All.aspx

And i have access for edit, read et create all things in your personal site
How to restrict the access ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal. Check with the farm admins to see if a group was added with permissions at the web application level, or perhaps a group was added as a user profile admin. Steps to configure the user profile administrators are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/ee721059(v=office.14)), and instructions for configuring web app permissions are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/manage-permissions-for-a-web-application).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to go to site settings->site collection features, find out “Limited-access user permission lockdown mode” feature, make sure it’s activated.

If the issue exists, go to site content->Documents library->Library settings->Permissions of this document library, check if there is permissions about the users.

Besides, as Mike said, the SharePoint collection administrators have full control permission which might cause this condition.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks you, it's work find.

I have another question, i search a document in my personal mysite (Search onedrive) and i have nothing result. Have you an idea ?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please do not post questions in the answer box. Start a new question if needed.